# Google Cloud SQL import - HTTPError 403: Insufficient Permission

Tags: google-cloud-sql

I would like to import mysql dump file into mysql database instance with the gcloud import tool, but I am getting an error:

```
ubuntu@machine:~/sql$ gcloud sql instances import sql-56-test-8ef0cb104575 gs://dbf/bt_ca_dev_tmp-2017-01-19.sql.gz
ERROR: (gcloud.sql.instances.import) HTTPError 403: Insufficient Permission
```

What exact permissions am I missing? I can create sql instance with registered service account but I am not possible to import data?

Comment: Sounds like you need to provide a logon of some sort. HTTP/403 is access denied.

Comment: I had this error and it went away when I specified --project

Answer (score 6):

You have issue with permissions

create a bucket if you don't have one, run

```
`gsutil mb -p [PROJECT_NAME] -l [LOCATION_NAME] gs://[BUCKET_NAME]`
```

Describe the sql instance you are exporting from and copy the sa

```
`gcloud sql instances describe [INSTANCE_NAME]`
```

Add the service account to the bucket ACL as a writer

```
`gsutil acl ch -u [SERVICE_ACCOUNT_ADDRESS]:W gs://[BUCKET_NAME]`
```

Add the service account to the import file as a reader

```
`gsutil acl ch -u [SERVICE_ACCOUNT_ADDRESS]:R gs://[BUCKET_NAME]/[IMPORT_FILE_NAME]`
```

Import the file:
`gcloud sql import csv [INSTANCE_NAME] gs://[BUCKET_NAME]/[FILE_NAME] \
                            --database=[DATABASE_NAME] --table=[TABLE_NAME]`

Comment: I had to recursively give read permissions to the database service account across my bucket. Is there a way to give this at the bucket level like with write permissions?

Comment: Why do you need to give WRITE permission for the bucket though?

Comment: @Pablo i'm not sure why, but it's required to add `legacyBucketWriter` permission for the cloud sql instance service account on the bucket you're importing from: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/import-export/importing

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/import-export/importing), this should do the trick. The wierd thing is that it needs write permissions. This should do the trick:

```
gsutil iam ch serviceAccount:"${SERVICE_ACCOUNT}":roles/storage.legacyBucketWriter gs://${BUCKET_NAME}
gsutil iam ch serviceAccount:"${SERVICE_ACCOUNT}":roles/storage.objectViewer gs://${BUCKET_NAME}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a permission problem of the Cloud SQL service account in the Google Storage bucket you're trying to use. To solve it you need to grant `Storage Legacy Bucket Reader`, `Storage Legacy Object Owner`, `Storage Object Viewer` roles to the service account email that you get from

```
gcloud sql instances describe <YOUR_DB_NAME> | grep serviceAccountEmailAddress
```

To do it go to the Cloud Storage / your bucket in Google Cloud Console and under `Permission` write the `serviceAccountEmailAddress` in `ADD`. Finally, add the roles you need.